# Navigation bar title font doesn't refresh at the right time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an navigation controller with few view controllers - let's call them `A`, `B`, `C` where each of them invokes another on navigation flow (`A` is root, `C` is on the top of the stack). Each of them has navigation bar with the same title attributes (`titleTextAttributes`) except `C` which has different font. I change it in the `viewDidLoad`() function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    primaryFont = navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?[NSAttributedStringKey.font] as? UIFont

    if let font: UIFont = UIFont.get(size: .small, family: .systemFont, style: .regular) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes![NSAttributedStringKey.font] = font
    }
}
```

Also when I go back from view controller C to B I set previous value of font:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if let font = primaryFont {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = font
    }
}
```

Code above looks fine for me but in fact title font of view controller `B` is the same as `C` (which shouldn't happen). When I go back to `A` it has correct font already (primary one) and after that when I go again to `B` it has correct font too this time.

While debugging all font values are correct but it seems that there is some UI refreshment issue (?)

Summarising: I want to change title font only for view controller `C` and I can't achieve it

Do you have any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

update: when I add another view controller `B'` in the middle `A`>`B`>`B'`>`C`. Correct fonts are on the `A` and `B`. `B'` has the wrong one when I go back from `C`

Comment: try in viewWill appear of viewController B

Comment: Also can you check whether your `primaryFont` variable has a value.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I've already tried this with no result

Comment: @Harsh primaryFont has correct value

Comment: try defining your primary font as constant, and just assign it

Comment: @ReinierMelian problem still remains

Comment: Did you find any solution?